# Entity framework code first, some advice needed

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity

I'm new to entity frame work code first.
I have simple class called Cat and a list of cats, when i'm doing the following :

```
mAllAnimals.Add(new Cat() { Father = null , Name = "Father Kitten", NickName = "Shmil" });
mAllAnimals.Add(new Cat() { Father = mAllAnimals.First(a => a.Name == "Father Kitten") , Name = "Son Kitten" , NickName = "son" });
```

i get an exception,because he couldn't find "Father kitten", but when i put between the to statements "SaveChanges()" it works perfectly.

This is very strange for me, do i actually need to save every step of the way ? can't he search on the local copy and on the db, i thought that part of the fun in entity framework is that i can work "normally" with my class and doesn't have to save my changes every step of the way.
Can i make him "auto save" every step i do, so i won't have to write all the time "SaveChanges"

One more question, i worked previously with NHibrnate and all the mapping where made using simple XML files. i don't see any files here, were is the mapping ? can i change it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the lack of an .edmx, see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/07/when-is-code-first-not-code-first.aspx

Code First does not use an .edmx file, and it is also called Code Only for that reason.  You do the mapping using attributes or fluent API.  See the first two posts in the 12-part series on the Entity Framework blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
Cat father = new Cat() { Father = null , Name = "Father Kitten", NickName = "Shmil" };
Cat son = new Cat() { Father = father , Name = "Son Kitten" , NickName = "son" };

mAllAnimals.Add(father);
mAllAnimals.Add(son);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The reason your version doesn't work is that you are looking for the `father` entity in the database - but you will only add it to the DB when you call `SaveChanges()`

As for the mapping - your project should have an `.edmx` file - double clicking that will bring up a designer which also allows you to modify the mapping.

Comment: But if i want to make the insertion in one transaction, i don't want him to save the father and then the son, want to save them together.

Comment: @OopsUser: They **are** added together - the changes are only committed to the DB (within a transaction) when you call `SaveChanges()`, until then they only live in memory within your context object.

Comment: Another thing is that my project does not contain any edmx files. I also clicked "show all files" in the solution explorer and still didn't found any edmx files.